# Indexing file names and its content

Tags: c++, regex, file, indexing, directory

I would like to write a program that index file names and its content in a given directory. If they match a given regular expression, then I would like to index them. I will use regex functions.

I don't really know how to start this.

I would use a polymorphic approach:

1. A class Base (virtual), with basic information (name, parent directory...).
2. A class File, a child of Base, which would represent a file.
3. A class Folder/directoy which would represent a directory.

I am also thinking about using map to build trees.

May you tell me your opinion about this please?

Answer (score 2):

For filesystem functionality, use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

For regular expressions, use [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) for C++11, [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) otherwise.

Any initial(!) trouble you might have when installing and learning Boost will very quickly pay off.

For your map, use `std::map`.

In any case, do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use Boost.Filesystem nor Boost.Regex. It is an homework and I can only use a few libraries.

Comment: @rusol: You must implement your own regular expressions? In a homework? Seriously? Well, what libraries are you allowed to use then? C++ itself does have near to nothing for filesystem access. At the very least, you will have to use a system library provided by your operating system. I still recommend having a look at Boost.Filesystem to get some inspiration. Personally, I would *not* use OOP here.

Comment: I am allowed to use regex functions, the standad C++ and C libraries. Not more unfortunately. Why wouldn't you use OOP?

Comment: @rusol: Because you do not gain much in turn for the increased complexity. Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/faq.htm: "Why isn't path a base class with derived directory_path and file_path classes?" In fact, also look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/design.htm, and you'll see how difficult it is to design a good filesystem library.